# stylesheet import error in build system

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I don't know why but this irregularity always happens in my Yeoman build system. In my `Gulpfile.js`, the directory where all `.scss` files will be watched is in `app/styles/**/*.scss`. The strategy I used is: the only compiled stylesheet that I would link to HTML file is the `main.scss`, where the other `.scss` files are already imported to. So when the compilation is done, only the `main.css` will be linked.

main.scss

```
@import 'base';

@import '_banner';
@import '_works';
@import '_design';
@import '_story';
@import '_contact';
```

Here is the image of the content of the folder where the stylesheets are located:
[image: folder]

The problem is, every time I make changes to one of any of my `.scss` files, it throws an error that refers to importing error; but when I try to make some changes again, the compilation is successful.
[image]

In my `Gulpfile.js`:

```
gulp.task('styles', () => {
  return gulp.src('app/styles/main.scss')
    .pipe($.plumber())
    .pipe($.if(dev, $.sourcemaps.init()))
    .pipe($.sass.sync({
      outputStyle: 'compressed',
      precision: 10,
      includePaths: ['.']
    }).on('error', $.sass.logError))
    .pipe($.autoprefixer({browsers: ['> 1%', 'last 2 versions', 'Firefox ESR']}))
    .pipe($.if(dev, $.sourcemaps.write()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/styles'))
    .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});
```

Is this some kind of a bug? What should I do to prevent this from happening again?

Comment: Does this always happen? I've run into issues if I `@import` a new file while gulp watch is running I have to restart the watch.

Comment: yes, it always happens